# Calculate response of an LTI system with infinite DC gain to an finite length input in time domain

Tags: linear-systems

I have given the transfer function $P(z)$ of an LTI system in z-domain.

Furthermore, I have a time-discrete finite length input signal $r$.

I want to calculate the system response $y$ in time domain.

The calculation must be implemented in a real-time system later.

If $P(z) = \frac{z \ T_s}{z\ (T_s+T_1)-T_1} $ (PT1 system) I can calculate the response using following steps:

1. Calculate the frequency response $P(j\omega)$ of $P(z)$
2. Calculate the Markov parameters of $P(j\omega)$ by calculating the inverse fourier transform
3. Calculate the lifted system representation/matrix response $P_{LS}$ using the Markov parameters
4. Calculate the system response as $y = P_{LS} \cdot r$

E.g. in MATLAB:

```
clear,clc
Ts = 1e-3;
fs = 1/Ts;
t = (0:Ts:0.3-Ts)'; % time vector
df = fs/length(t);
fnyq = fs/2;
f = [0:df:fnyq-df, fnyq ,-fnyq+df:df:-df]; % frequency arr. (corresp. to matlab fft)
w = 2*pi*f; % frequency vector in rad
z = exp(1i*w*Ts);
r = zeros(size(t)); r(t > t(end)/2) = 1; % input signal
T1 = 1/(2*pi*100); % time constant PT1
P = z*Ts./(z*(Ts+T1)-T1); % PT1
markovParams = ifft(P,'symmetric'); % Markov parameters
p = tril(toeplitz(markovParams)); % Lifted system representation
y = p * r; % system response

figure(1),clf,hold on
plot(t, r)
plot(t, y)
legend('Input', 'Output')
xlabel('Time / s')
```

However if $H(z) = \frac{z^2 \ T_s^2}{z^2 - 2z + 1}$ (double integrator) I can't calculate the Markov parameters in this way since the first element of P is `Inf`.

I know that another way to calculate the lifted system representation is possible if one has a state-space representation of the system but I would prefer to use a solution which is based on the transfer function.

**My question is:** is there another way to calculate the Markov parameters/lifted system representation/system response to overcome this issue?

Comment: Your second system has a double pole on the unit circle at $z=0$ so it's only marginally stable.

Comment: @Hilmar $\omega = 0$ or $z=1$, but yes.

Comment: Oops. sorry. it's $z=1$

Comment: I know but is that/why is that a reason that I can't do it in this way?